# Equivalent of "Open Implementation" for C in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c, ide, openssl, eclipse-cdt, code-search

I have a C project on Eclipse CDT, which makes use of the OpenSSL library.
I correctly configured the library and include paths, so as a result I can open declaration of functions inside the editor (I mean the **.h** header files) (by pressing F3, or clicking *Open Declaration*).

I'm now looking for a quick way to open the functions' *implementation*, like I could do in Java with the usual `Ctrl + Click`.

**Is there such a thing for C in Eclipse CDT?**

I'm looking for anything more practical than a *Search* in Eclipse after importing the code, or than a `find . -name "*.c" | xargs grep -li function_name` in the OpenSSL source directory.

Comment: Did you compile OpenSSL from its source code? What is your operating system and compiler (and version)?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to `Ctrl` + `Click` on the declared function name to go to the definition.
There's also this handy little shortcut:

`Ctrl` + `Tab`: Switch between source and header files.